# How to control framework exchanges between webserver and client in C?

Tags: html, c, sockets, webserver, tcp

I'm a novice in programming and my mission is to program a webserver based on a WIZnet w5200.
I develop all the function that control and generate my socket but now I need to print a web page with just few data on it.
In fact their will be a PC connected to the WIZnet via Ethernet wire and what I want to do is opening a web page with internet explorer on this PC.
For instance I get some weird framework on Wireshark and "HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH...etc" on my internet explorer screen (edit-->no more weird framework or mutliple"H"). I developped functions that create dynamically html code.
Here is some part of my code, tell me if something is choking (except the fact that it is weird) :

```
switch(Get_S0_SR())
 {
    case SOCK_ESTABLISHED:
         printf("\n\n  establish  \n\n");
         /*if(Get_S0_RX_RSR()!=0)                 //on regarde si on a reçu des data
         {
             printf("\n\nsize recv = %x\n\n",Get_S0_RX_RSR());
             recv_data=recv_Socket();         //si oui on procède à la reception de ces données

         }*/
         //if(analog_data!=0)                     //on regarde si on as une donnée analogique
         //{
             printf("\n\ndeuxieme\n\n");
             val=0;
             while(val!=1)
             {
                val=send_Socket();//on envoi cette donnée via ethernet
                printf("\n\nFINI\n\n");
             }

         //}
         //else
         //{
            //goto SOCK_CLOSE_WAIT;
            disconnect_Socket();
            printf("\n\ndisconnect\n\n");
         //}
         break; 

    case SOCK_CLOSE_WAIT:
         printf("\n\nSOCK_CLOSE_WAIT\n\n");
         if(Get_S0_RX_RSR()!=0)               //on regarde si on a reçu des data
         {
             recv_data=recv_Socket();         //si oui on procède à la reception de ces données
             disconnect_Socket();             //une fois le processus finis on se deconnecte
             //goto SOCK_CLOSED;
         }
         if(Get_S0_IR()==S0_IR_TIMEOUT)
         {
             //goto SOCK_CLOSED;
             disconnect_Socket();
         }
         else
         {   
             //goto SOCK_ESTABLISHED;
             disconnect_Socket();
         }
         break;  

    case SOCK_CLOSED:
         printf("\n\nSOCK_CLOSE\n\n");
         close_Socket();
         break;

    case SOCK_INIT:
         val=listen_Socket();
         while(Get_S0_SR()!=SOCK_ESTABLISHED)
         {
            printf("\n\non attend la connection\n\n");
            //delay(1000);
         }
         printf("\n\nstatu=%x\n\n",Get_S0_SR());
         delay(1000);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
//printf("\n\nstatu=%x\n\n",Get_S0_SR());
return ;
```

}

One more update :

I use strcpy() to fill my buffer with html (as displayed on the code at the bottom) and I get the web page that I want (except for the data contained in "tracabilite[]"). The only problem is that I display the same paragraph several times ! Just like my "HHHHHHHHHH...etc" problem before. I think it comes from the transmission buffer of the WIZnet. Does its size is supposed to be initialize at the exact length of the HTTP frame ?
I try to figure it out but for instance I don't.

Here is the new code to generate html:

```
   unsigned short debut_trame(void)
{
  //unsigned char idx;
  unsigned short taille;
  //on vas stocker notre chaine de caractère html grace à strcpy
  strcpy(Write_Com_WIZnet,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\rContent-Type:Text/html; 
<charset=utf-8>\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<h1>Donnees de soudure</h1><p>"); 
  taille=strlen("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\rContent-Type:Text/html; <charset=utf-
8>\r\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<h1>Donnees de soudure</h1><p>");
  printf("\ntaille trame=%d",taille);
  //on vas écrire cette chaine de caractère dans le buffer TX   
  write_WIZnet(0x8000,taille);
  return taille;
}

unsigned short liste_analog_data(unsigned short taille)
{
  unsigned short len;
  strcpy(Write_Com_WIZnet,"Puissance_Alim=");
  len=strlen("Puissance_Alim=");
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len]=tracabilite[0];
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len+1]=tracabilite[1];
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len+2)),"<br />");
  len+=strlen("<br />")+2;
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len)),"Courant_Alim=");
  len+=strlen("Courant_Alim=");
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len]=tracabilite[2];
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len+1]=tracabilite[3];
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len+2)),"<br />");
  len+=strlen("<br />")+2;
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len)),"Tension_Alim=");
  len+=strlen("Tension_Alim=");
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len]=tracabilite[4];
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len+1]=tracabilite[5];
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len+2)),"<br />");
  len+=strlen("<br />")+2;
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len)),"Courant_Generateur=");
  len+=strlen("Courant_Generateur=");
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len]=tracabilite[6];
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len+1]=tracabilite[7];
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len+2)),"<br />");
  len+=strlen("<br />")+2;
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len)),"Frequence=");
  len+=strlen("Frequence=");
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len]=tracabilite[8];
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len+1]=tracabilite[9];
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len+2)),"<br />");
  len+=strlen("<br />")+2;
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len)),"Temps_Soudure=");
  len+=strlen("Temps_Soudure=");
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len]=tracabilite[10];
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len+1]=tracabilite[11];
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len+2)),"<br />");
  len+=strlen("<br />")+2;
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len)),"Statut=");
  len+=strlen("Statut=");
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len]=tracabilite[12];
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len+1]=tracabilite[13];
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len+2)),"<br />");
  len+=strlen("<br />")+2;
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len)),"SWR=");
  len+=strlen("SWR=");
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len]=tracabilite[14];
  Write_Com_WIZnet[len+1]=tracabilite[15];
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len+2)),"<br />");
  len+=strlen("<br />")+2;
  strcpy((Write_Com_WIZnet+(len)),"</p>\n</body>\n</html>\0");
  len+=strlen("</p>\n</body>\n</html>\0");
  write_WIZnet(0x8000+taille,len);
  taille+=len;
  return taille;
}


void genere_HTML(void)
{
  unsigned short size, size2;
  printf("\non genere la page\n");
  size=debut_trame();
  size2=liste_analog_data(size);
  //size2+=size;
  printf("\nenvoi de la page au WIZnet, taille=%x\n",size2);
  //write_WIZnet(0x8000,size2);
}
```

I know it is ugly but it's working (at least for the look)... The problem is that I display it several times. 
Any help about HTTP, HTML or anything else will be usefull !

Comment: `Write_Com_WIZnet[i]=data_html(i);` Are you aware that `data_html()` is called with `idx` running from 65 upwards? This way to copy string literals is terribly inefficient, btw.

Comment: Hi @Gerhardh , In fact I fill Write_Com_WIZnet[] with the HTML string (well, I'm trying to...) and then I send all the values to WIZnet with write_WIZnet(), as Write_Com_WIZnet is an extern chart I re-use it in write_WIZnet to send its content on SPI bus. If you have better ideas I'm fully aware !

Comment: First of all you should fix your buffer overflow when you call `data_html` or `bottom_html` with values way beyond the boundaries of the arrays they access.

Comment: For efficiency you could just make your functions prepare and return a buffer. Then you can loop through this buffer outside of these functions. Maybe some function within family of `strcpy` or `memcpy` can be used. Calling the function for each separate character is much overhead.

Comment: Maybe you could add the TCP frame that was captured by Wireshark. Then we could see what you send to the client. Is the HTML payload broken or is the TCP or IP part broken...

Comment: I don't know if you could read them correctly but :
https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/6f5fb4129937
Here they are !

Comment: I tried to do a wetransfer but it doesn't work ! Stack overflow doesn't want me to show you the frames ... except via the link before !

Comment: When I paste the wetransfer link, stackoverflow doesn't want it and ask me to use "meta" .. I didn't achieve it ! Still trying

Comment: Allright thanks very much @Gerhardh .. here it is : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6cc16fb406fb5f4ddf041104dc18249820170620070344/24e01e

Comment: While pdf file are extremely unsuitable for the purpse you can see that the context "HTTP 1.1 200 OK" only starts more than 60 bytes after the start of HTTP data field. It should start at 0. The position where you copy your data is wrong or the way to initiate transmitting the data is not correct.

Comment: Here is another one https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b207dff116b05ca783152716401b1c4f20170620110631/7ee2d2
I use the physical address of the transmit buffer... I tried to understand where this delay come from, in vain !

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer but too much for comments.
I've also cleaned up a few of my comments related to providing the sample file.

With your changed function to create HTML content, the text is copied correctly.

But looking at frame #8 of your Wireshark file you can see that the HTTP data does not start with the content you prepared does not start at byte #0. Instead it starts much later.
HTTP data part of the frame starts at offset 0x36. Yout text is visible from offset 0x220.
I don't know where you can configure which buffer ist used as content of your TCP connection, but you are off by 490 bytes here.

Another issue is visible. If you look at the TCP stream, you can see that the data transmitted is ~40KiB which is far too much.

In the content you can spot multiple copies of your prepared content but only 1 GET request.

From your function I can see some new problem:

```
unsigned char* genere_HTML(void)
{
  unsigned char* return_strcpy;
  strcpy(Write_Com_WIZnet,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type:Text/html; 
  charset=utf-8\n\n<html>\n<body>\n<h1>\n1 2 3 4\n</h1>\n</body>\n</html>");
  write_WIZnet(0x8000,200);
  return return_strcpy;
}
```

Here you return the uninitialized content of `return_strcpy`. Whatever is done with the return value of that function, it cannot be any good.

Also you use hard coded parameters for `write_WIZnet`. No hint about the length of the content or the storage location.
Assuming that `Write_Com_WIZnet` is used implicitely, you still have no length information.

I also don't have any information what these values are supposed to mean.

Wherever your buffer is transmitted, the problem is not in the part visible in this question.

Comment: Thanks for those indication @Gerhardh I will try hard to find out what happen with my transmit buffer !